Python google cloud function won't import pandas
I’m having a problem where I’m trying to deploy a google cloud function and have narrowed down the source of the problem to the import of pandas in the function. But the strange thing is that this was working for me a few days ago and then suddenly stopped working and it took quite a bit of time to narrow down and figure out exactly what was going wrong. To summarize, I have a test_fcn that is laid out below and it won’t deploy. However, if I comment out the “import pandas” line then the function deploys correctly. At this point, the function doesn’t do anything: it’s just a test vehicle to demonstrate the problem. I’m confused and would like to know how to get pandas to import properly because I need to use that library for running my real function. And, to repeat myself, the real function was running a few days ago but when I redeployed the “last successful deployment” yesterday it failed. Has anyone seen this problem or a similar problem and know what might be going on?
 
Here is the requirements.txt
functions-framework==3.*

pandas==2.0.3

 

And here is the test function:
import pandas as p
import functions_framework
 
@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
 
    response = run_test_fcn()
    return 'ok', 200
 
def run_test_fcn():
  return 'ok'
 
Here is the log output, starting with the first traceback
ERROR 2024-06-17T17:28:38.213663Z Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/functions-framework", line 8, in <module> sys.exit(_cli())
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.213686Z ^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.213692Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in _call_
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.214692Z return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.214866Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.214874Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.215191Z rv = self.invoke(ctx)
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.215296Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.215312Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.215689Z return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.215907Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.215918Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.216116Z return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.216213Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.216219Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/functions_framework/_cli.py", line 36, in _cli
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.217937Z app = create_app(target, source, signature_type)
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.218094Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.218111Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/functions_framework/_init_.py", line 395, in create_app
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.219695Z raise e from None
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.219716Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/functions_framework/_init_.py", line 376, in create_app
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.219860Z spec.loader.exec_module(source_module)
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.219897Z File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.219904Z File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.219909Z File "/workspace/main.py", line 1, in <module>
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.219971Z import pandas
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.219993Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/_init_.py", line 22, in <module>
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.221548Z from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev # pyright: ignore # noqa:F401
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.221728Z ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.221734Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/compat/_init_.py", line 25, in <module>
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.223044Z from pandas.compat.numpy import (
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.223060Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/_init_.py", line 4, in <module>
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.224803Z from pandas.util.version import Version
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.224814Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/_init_.py", line 2, in <module>
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.226038Z from pandas.util._decorators import ( # noqa:F401
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.226048Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 14, in <module>
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.228236Z from pandas._libs.properties import cache_readonly
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.228265Z File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/_libs/_init_.py", line 13, in <module>
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.228801Z from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.228810Z File "pandas/_libs/interval.pyx", line 1, in init pandas._libs.interval
WARNING 2024-06-17T17:28:38.932291632Z Container called exit(1).
DEFAULT 2024-06-17T17:28:38.932507Z ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject
ERROR 2024-06-17T17:28:39.021017Z Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container "worker" on port 8080. The instance was not started.
ERROR 2024-06-17T17:28:39.037091Z [protoPayload.serviceName: run.googleapis.com] [protoPayload.methodName: v1] [protoPayload.resourceName: namespaces/sample-datasets-400819/revisions/test-fcn-00009-dew] Ready condition status changed to False for Revision test-fcn-00009-dew with message: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information. Logs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=sample-datasets-400819&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/test-fcn/revision_name/test-fcn-00009-dew&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22test-fcn%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22test-fcn-00009-dew%22 For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start
ERROR 2024-06-17T17:28:39.134491Z [protoPayload.serviceName: run.googleapis.com] [protoPayload.methodName: v1] [protoPayload.resourceName: namespaces/sample-datasets-400819/services/test-fcn] Ready condition status changed to False for Service test-fcn with message: Revision 'test-fcn-00009-dew' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information. Logs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=sample-datasets-400819&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/test-fcn/revision_name/test-fcn-00009-dew&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22test-fcn%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22test-fcn-00009-dew%22 For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start
ERROR 2024-06-17T17:28:39.314237610Z [protoPayload.serviceName: cloudfunctions.googleapis.com] [protoPayload.methodName: google.cloud.functions.v2.FunctionService.UpdateFunction] [protoPayload.resourceName: projects/sample-datasets-400819/locations/us-central1/functions/test_fcn] [protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail: rudy@datacakes.ai] Could not create or update Cloud Run service test-fcn, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'test-fcn-00009-dew' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information. Logs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=sample-datasets-400819&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/test-fcn/revision_name/test-fcn-00009-dew&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22test-fcn%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22test-fcn-00009-dew%22 For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start
The first line of the traceback ends abruptly on the first line of code so it is not really telling me that the problem is with pandas which is also confusing. However, I have verified that commenting out the "import pandas" line makes it so that the function deploys correctly and uncommenting it yields the traceback shown above. Help anyone?
I tried all combinations of including code and import statements. The only thing that seems to reliably invoke the error is the inclusing of the "import pandas" line and it doesn't matter whether it's "import pandas as pd" or not. The error is the same, as you would expect.

Looks like from the error that it's a compatibility issue between numpy and pandas.
Try installing newer version of pandas:
sudo pip install --upgrade pandas

If that still doesn't help, try upgrading numpy as well:
sudo pip install --upgrade numpy


Hi, your answer gave me an idea to check the version of numpy that was running. As it turns out, numpy was just upgraded to 2.0.0 yesterday when my problems started happening. So I added the following line to my requirements.txt file: numpy<2.0.0 and that seems to have solved the problem! Sure enough, if I set numpy==2.0.0 it fails again, so I think we can say this problem is solved. It seems to be due to an incompatiblity between pandas 2.0.3 and numpy 2.0.0.
